# How to save a folded code structure after file close

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I save folded code structure after file close? It get me a lot of headache to fold a lot of code again each time when I reopen file.

Comment: Code folding state is saved in `.idea/workspace.xml` file.

Comment: @CrazyCoder well, it`s ok. But what kind of useful information it gives me?

Comment: If it doesn't persist for you, you should report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project attached, [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) and the exact steps to reproduce it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I`m not sure that this is a bug.

Comment: It's a bug because I can't reproduce the issue and folding persists after file is closed and opened again.

Comment: @CrazyCoder ok. I if it`s not difficult for you, can you try to make this steps:
1. Create a local branch 
2. Add some code
3. Fold it
4. Commit your changes
5. Switch to a another branch and merge changes.
6. Then check file again?

Comment: See [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839). Since `.idea/workspace.xml` is not shared by default in the version control, switching branches may render folding information stored in this file inaccurate for the version of the files you have.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save the particular state of the code folds as far as I know, but you can collapse certain code regions by default as shown here in the preferences.

[image: IntelliJ Preferences/ Settings]

What I do is use `//region` and `//endregion` for my custom folding code I want collapsed, and use documentation for things I want always seen (like explaining what is inside the code folds' logic where necessary).